# unix cut to extract column from text file and save rest of the contents to a new file

Tags: unix

I can do the following using unix `cut` :

```
cut -f 1 myfile.out
```

Output:

```
6DKK463WXXK
VKFQ9PYP9CG
```

Since its printing out the column that I want to extract. How do I create the a new file without this column? In other words, I want to remove this column now and keep the rest of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your version of Unix, you may use the negate option to select the fields not listed.

```
cut -f 2 --complement myfile.input > myfile.output
```

That will place all the columns from the input file into the output file, except for column 2.

You use the `-d` argument to specify a delimiter other than tab, which is the default.

Note from experience: Be careful with the `>` especially when using similar names for input and output so that you don't accidentally overwrite your input file (using tab completion, this is easy to do).

Example:

```
% echo one two three | cut -d ' ' -f 2 --complement
> one three
```

Answer (score 0):

Gdang! S.O. must be swamped right now.

This is very easy in awk

```
 echo "1 2 3    4 5" | awk -F" " '{sub(/[^ ]+ /,""); print}'
```

**output**

```
2 3    4 5
```

Deletes everything upto the first space character.
The the remaining record is printed.

IHTH

Comment: hopefully fixed edits are now in place. Having trouble with S.O. saving extra copies, missing edits, etc.